# Изменяющаяся общая высота блока при скрытии/появлении другого блока div

Tags: jquery, javascript

Здравствуйте.

Прошу помощи.

Вкратце, есть общий DIV-блок (фильтр поиска) с определенной высотой, допустим, 170px.

При выборе в селекте значения автоматически ниже появляется другой блок с тестовыми формами.

Соответственно, меняется высота у общего DIV-блока на 250px.

Все хорошо работает, только вот немного коряво.

При выбранных всех значениях после нажатия на кнопку Отправить сам общий DIV-блок меняет высоту на 170px. Что неправильно.

Прошу помощи в доработке скрипта, где я недосмотрел:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("select.all_rubric").live('change',function(){
$(".filter").css({'height':'170px'});
  $("div.working").each(function (i) {
    if (this.style.display != "none") {
        $(".filter").css({'height':'250px'});
    } else {
        //
    }
  });
});
});
```

//-- HTML --//

```
<div class="filter_item">
    <div class="f_rubric">
    <div class="filter_first_block">
    <select class="all_rubric">
        <option>Все рубрики</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    <div class="filter_second_block">
        <input type="text" class="" placeholder="Поиск по сайту..." />
    </div>
    <div class="filter_last_block">
        <a class="btn" href="#"><img src="images/icons/search_icon.png">Найти</a>
    </div>
    </div>
<div class="working">
//Другие текстовые формы и селекты
</div>
</div>
```

Обработчик на кнопку Отправить.

```
<a id="find" class="btn" href="#" onclick="document.forms.arrFilter_form.submit();return false;">Найти</a>
```

Comment: [live()][1] удалено из jquery 1.7+, используйте [on()][2]. А вообще покажите ваш html и обработчик отправки. По идее, при отправке страница обновляется и следовательно срабатывает стиль: `$(".filter").css({'height':'170px'});`


  [1]: http://api.jquery.com/live/
  [2]: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Пробовал on() Не помогает.

Comment: @Kirill  Seleznev, `on()` и не должно помочь, это просто рекомендация, html лучше перенести в вопрос, а также не увидел скрипта обработки данных по нажатию кнопки "отправить", да и самой кнопки и формы в html не увидел, чтобы решить проблему, нужно больше данных

Comment: @Kirill  Seleznev, html-код кнопки есть, теперь остался код обработчика, а именно код функции `document.forms.arrFilter_form.submit()`.

Comment: Тут не все так просто, сайт на Битриксе. Обработчик работает по методу GET. action="<?echo $arResult["FORM_ACTION"]?>"
К запросу подключается дополнительные данные и заносятся в массив результатов работы компонента $arResult.

Соответственно запрос в адресной строке становится таким:
board_new/?arrFilter_ff%5BSECTION_ID%5D=168&arrFilter_ff%5BINCLUDE_SUBSECTIONS%5D=Y&arrFilter_ff%5BNAME%5D=&arrFilter_pf%5BSCOPE%5D=&arrFilter_pf%5BFEE%5D=&arrFilter_pf%5BEXPERIENCE%5D=&arrFilter_pf%5BSCOPE%5D=&arrFilter_...

Вывести весь код обработчика не предоставляется возможным, так как он слишком длинный.